# Jax Rs MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jax-ws

I have wrote a JAX-RS server and client both use Jersey. I want to sent a collection of my entities to client

{​​​​​​ "codeHttp": 500, "message": "MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/json, type=class fr.pe.coct.exposition.ex089.beans.EvenementDto, genericType=class fr.pe.coct.exposition.ex089.beans.EvenementDto."}​​​​​​

> **Interface : MeeEvenementREST.class**

```
@Path("mee/v1/evenement")
public interface MeeEvenementREST {
    @GET
    @Path("/detail/{id}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8"})
    @OperationRestSLD
    @ResponseStatus(value = {Response.Status.OK, Response.Status.NO_CONTENT, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST,
            Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED, Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR})
    @IdentificationSeule
    Response meeGetEvenementById(@PathParam("id") long id);
}
```

> classe : MeeEvenementREST.class

```
public class EvenementRestImpl implements MeeEvenementREST {

    @Inject
    ServiceDA148 evenementService;

    @Override
    public Response meeGetEvenementById(long id) {
        LOGGER.info("########### Appel OK de service GET evenement/{id} ###########");
        EvenementDto evenementDto = evenementService.meeGetEvenementById(id);
        return Response.ok(evenementDto, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
```

> class : ServiceDA148.class

```
public class ServiceDA148 {
public EvenementDto meeGetEvenementById(Long id) {
        EvenementDto meeEvenementOUT = null;
        Response response = null;

        try {
            final Invocation.Builder builder = fournisseurSLDCibleRest
                    .getCible()
                    .path(ConstantesDA148.V1_PATH)
                    .path(ConstantesDA148.EVENEMENT_PATH)
                    .path(ConstantesDA148.EVENEMENT_PATH_BY_ID)
                    .path("/"+id)
                    .request(ConstantesDA148.MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON_UTF_8)
                    .accept(ConstantesDA148.MEDIA_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON);

            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug(APPEL_DU_DA148, ConstantesDA148.V1_PATH + ConstantesDA148.EVENEMENT_PATH_BY_ID + "/" + id );
            }
            response = builder.get();

            LOGGER.debug(RETOUR_DU_DA148, response.getStatus());

            if (response.getStatusInfo().getStatusCode() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
                meeEvenementOUT = response.readEntity(EvenementDto.class);
            } else {
                final ErreurRestSLDNG erreur = response.readEntity(ErreurRestSLDNG.class);
                LOGGER.error(APPEL_DU_DA148, ConstantesDA148.V1_PATH + ConstantesDA148.EVENEMENT_PATH + ConstantesDA148.EVENEMENT_PATH_BY_ID, erreur);
            }
        } finally {
            if (response != null) {
                response.close();
            }
        }
        return meeEvenementOUT;

    }
```

> pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The error is with your client call. The JSOn provider is not being register with your client

Comment: You have the `<scope>provided</scope>`. This means that the server should have this dependency. If it doesn't, then the JSON serialization will not work unless there is another provider (that works with POJOs)